# How to concatenate charlist in Elixir

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, two strings can be concatenated with `<>` like below:

```
iex(1)> "Hello" <> " World" 
"Hello World"
```

how to concatenate two charlists? I got below error if I use `<>`.

```
iex(2)> 'Hello' <> ' World'
** (CompileError) iex:2: invalid literal 'Hello' in <<>>
    (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:19: :elixir_bitstring.expand/6
    (elixir) src/elixir_bitstring.erl:12: :elixir_bitstring.expand/4
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.<>/2
    iex:2: (file)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Charlists are just lists, so the operator to concatenate lists, `++`, works for charlists as well:

```
iex(1)> 'Hello' ++ ' World'
'Hello World'
```